# Copying and Converting a File to Binary File in C with System Calls

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I'm currently working on a program that has to duplicate any file into a binary file using system calls ( open(), write(), read() etc... ). This is what have so far.

```
void copyFileToFD(int destinationFD, int sourceFD){
    unsigned char b[64];
    int amountRead = -1;
    while((amountRead = read(sourceFD, &b, 64)) > 0){
        int written = write(destinationFD, &b, amountRead);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having right now is with text files.

Suppose a file has this text:

> This is some text 12345678

My current output file shows

> This is some text 12345678

MY desired output file ()

> ABCD EF00 0000 0000 0000 0000...

How can I change my code so that all files will be copied as a binary file

I am aware of fread() and fwrite() but would like to know how this can be done with system calls.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You've got a strange definition of "binary file".  Where did "ABCD EF00 0000 0000 0000 0000" come from?  Do you mean "5468 6973 2069 7320 736f 6d65 2074 6578 7420 3132 3334 3536 3738"?

Comment: My editor opens up binary files in a way that represents them in such a format. "XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX...". Maybe I'm a bit confused about what binary files actually are.

Comment: If you have a binary file containing the 14 bytes "48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 0a", it contains the 14 bytes "48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 0a".  If you have a text file containing the 14 characters "Hello, world!\n", it contains the 14 bytes "48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 0a".  Under a modern operating system, the distinction between "text" and "binary" files is mostly one of interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to translate the input into hexadecimal text output.  You can do it using `printf()`:

```
void copyFileToFD(int destinationFD, int sourceFD){
    unsigned char ch;
    ssize_t amountRead = -1;
    while((amountRead = read(sourceFD, &ch, sizeof(ch))) > 0){
        dprintf(destinationFD, "%.2x ", ch);
    }
}
```